# C# Download an image from URL

Tags: c#, image, url, bitmap, server

I use a website to get stats on wifi usage. The website creates an image of a graph representation of the data. The way it does this is by the user, setting a date. So for example, lets say it was last months statistics. The website generates a URL which is then sent to the server and the server returns an image. an examples of the link is like this:

https://www.example.com/graph/daily_usage?time_from=2015-06-01+00%3A00%3A00+%2B0100&time_to=2015-06-30+23%3A59%3A59+%2B0100&tsp=1436519988

The problem is, I am making a third party program that will download this image to be used in my program. However, I cannot use the file. It is as if the file is corrupt or something. I have tried a few methods but maybe someone can suggest a different approach. **Basically, how do I download an image that is generated by a server from a URL link?**

**P.S.**

Just noticed that if I download the file by right clicking through a browser and save, the image downloads with a size of 17.something kilobytes. But if I use the WebClient method to download the image, it only downloads 1.5kb. Why would that be? Seems like the WebClient method does not download completely.

**Currently my code**

```
if (hrefAtt == "Usage Graph")
{
    string url = element.getAttribute("src");
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    client.DownloadFile(url, tempFolderPath + "\\" + currentAcc + "_UsageSummary.png");
    wd.AddImagesToDoc(tempFolderPath + "\\" + currentAcc + "_UsageSummary.png");
    wd.SaveDocument();
}
```

TempFolderPath is my desktop\TempFolder\

**UPDATE**
Out of random, I decided to see the raw data of the file with notepad and interestingly, the image data was actually a copy of the websites homepage html code, not the raw data of the image :S how does that make sense?

Comment: What approaches did you use?

Comment: So far, I have tried using WebClient method which DID download the file, but when I try to open it, the image was corrupted? Even though I set it to a .jpg. Another method I tried was just setting an Image_Box control on the wpf window and setting the source of the image as the URL but that did not work either (was doing it for testing purposes. my intention is for it to download the file)

Comment: Show us the code that uses the webclient and downloads a corrupted file

Comment: Added the code above. Looked bad in the comments here lol

Answer (score 2):

This will download the Google logo:

```
var img = Bitmap.FromStream(new MemoryStream(new WebClient().DownloadData("https://www.google.co.uk/images/srpr/logo11w.png")));
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice Dave, but I can't set the Image_Box control source in WPF because they are not compatible types. I tried casting but it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have to understand link texture. If all links are same or close to each other, you have to use substring/remove/datetime etc. methods to make your new request link. For example;

```
string today = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
string generatedLink = @"http://www.yoururl.com/image + " + today + ".jpg";
string generatedFileName = @"C:\Usage\usage + " + today + ".jpg";

WebClient wClient = new WebClient();
wClient.DownloadFile(generatedLink, generatedFileName);
```

Comment: I tried using the WebClient method and it did download A file but its as if it was corrupted